# Why does this python left rotation of an array not work

Tags: python, arrays

I have been trying the HackerRank practice problems and I can't figure out why my left rotate algorithm won't work. I have looked online but I can't see anyone trying to do it the same way I am. Any help would be much appreciated.

a = the array
d = the number of left rotations

example:
a = 1 2 3 4 5
d = 4

out = 5 1 2 3 4

```py
def rotLeft(a, d):
    out = a
    length = len(a)
    startingposition = 0

    for number in a:
        position = startingposition
        for count in range(d):
            position -= 1
            if position == -1:
                position = length 
        startingposition += 1
        out[position] = number

    return(out)
```

Comment: Parameters and expected output please

Comment: Do you think that `out = a` makes a copy of `a`? It doesn't. It just creates another reference to `a`. So `out[position]` makes changes in `a`. Can this be the reason your code doesn't work?

Comment: I get the way you try to solve this, but the loop with `position` plus the `if` would be better using `mod`

Comment: I suppose that this is the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation/problem

Comment: If you want to rotate `a` in place, return `None`. If you want to create a new rotated from, leave `a` unchanged and return the new list. Don't mix the two approaches unless you have a *very* good reason.

Comment: @Bharel I have now updated it, hope that's clearer

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks for your help, I think that array copying may have been part of the issue but I have now change it to out = a.copy() and I am still getting this error IndexError: list assignment index out of range. Yes it is that HackerRank problem

Comment: Add `print(f"{position=}")` before `out[position] = number` to see what value `position` has when it crashes.

Comment: @md2perpe thanks so much for your help! I tried that and found that they position was going to one higher than was available. I added -1 to length.            if position == -1:
                position = length - 1 and it worked!

Comment: [Off-by-one errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) are common. It has even [been written](https://twitter.com/secretGeek/status/7269997868) that "There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors."

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have solved it, I can add a couple of other solutions.

First a simple one:

```py
def rotLeft1(a):
    return a[1:] + [a[0]]

def rotLeft(a, d):
    for _ in range(d):
        a = rotLeft1(a)
    return a
```

Then one that doesn't make one step at a time:

```py
def rotLeft(a, d):
    i = d % len(a)
    return a[i:] + a[:i]
```

Comment: Very impressive how you can make it in such a simple way!

Comment: @ChristianFinn. Do you understand how it works?